# Pickle.load in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having trouble with a MainWindow using pickle to load serialized data.
Just a simple MainWindow

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, UI.MainUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.action_save.triggered.connect(self.save)
        self.action_load.triggered.connect(self.load)

    def save(self):
        with open("Save", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(self.test, f)

    def load(self):
        with open("Save", "rb") as f:
        self.test = pickle.load(f)

    def go(self):
        self.test = Test(14)

class Test():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

I can't get the save to happen as a runtime error occurs even though I do call the super of MainWindow:

```
self.test = pickle.load(f)
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MainWindow was never called
```

Comment: You need to include _all_ the code necessary to produce the error, and the _full_ traceback.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it broke like this for my basic code. I'll rework it.  Thank you.

Comment: @ekhumoro I can't make the error happen with any watered down version that I can make.  Is there a standard practice for this?  Should I just share my github repo?  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Without wishing to be too harsh: SO is not a debugging service. You should understand your code well enough to be able to isolate the problem. Or are you saying you don't know how to debug code? When it comes to python, you don't need to be too subtle. Just comment big chunks out in such a way that the program will still (sort of) work but the problem remains. Keep going until the problem disappears, then start adding little bits back until it reappears. No python code is so complex that this won't work eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the Advice.  I'll keep plugging away at it.  I just didn't want to overwhelm a forum with a tl;dr question.  Still learning and definitely still learning how to properly debug.  Thanks again.