# How to prevent a RuntimeError when unpickling a QObject?

Tags: python, pyqt, pickle

Trying to unpickle a pickled `QObject` (using Python 2.7, PyQt4 or 5, pickle or cPickle), raises the following `RuntimeError`:

`RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type QObject was never called`

A minimal example:

`cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(QtCore.QObject(), cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))`

I am aware that unpickling an object, by design, does not call the object's `__init__()` method.

How, then, can I make sure the superclass `__init__()` is called, in this case?

A seemingly similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20985770), but was not answered.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23738286), can be implemented as follows (a slightly more elaborate example, with a custom attribute):

```
import cPickle
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class MyQObject(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQObject, self).__init__(parent)
        # Add some custom attribute
        self.some_attribute = 'something'

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # Restore attributes
        self.__dict__.update(state)
        # Call the superclass __init__()
        super(MyQObject, self).__init__()

original = MyQObject()
pickle_string = cPickle.dumps(original, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
restored = cPickle.loads(pickle_string)
```

The parent can then be set using `setParent()`, if necessary.